# How to enable spec testing in Origen

Tags: origen-sdk

As we are getting our app near production readiness, we have written lots of spec tests.  Initially we were using `bundle exec rspec spec/myspec_spec.rb` to run individual files.  When I tried the `origen specs` command it didn't recotgnize the command as I expected.

```
peologin02:ppekit $ origen specs
Error: Command not recognized: specs
Usage: origen COMMAND [ARGS]

The core origen commands are:
 environment        Display or set the environment (short-cut alias: "e")
 target             Display or set the target (short-cut alias: "t")
 mode               Display or set the mode (short-cut alias: "m")
 plugin             Display or set the plugin (short-cut alias: "pl")
 generate           Generate a test pattern (short-cut alias: "g")
 program            Generate a test program (short-cut alias: "p")
 interactive        Start an interactive Origen console (short-cut alias: "i")
 compile            Compile a template file or directory (short-cut alias: "c")
 exec               Execute any Ruby file with access to your app environment

 rc                 Revision control commands, see -h for details
 save               Save the new or changed files from the last run or a given log file
 lsf                Monitor and manage LSF jobs (short-cut alias: "l")
 web                Web page tools, see -h for details
 time               Tools for test time analysis and forecasting
 lint               Lint and style check (and correct) your application code
```

I don't see anything about spec testing at the [main website](http://origen-sdk.org).

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implementation for `origen_specs` is included in the new app templates, but it is commented out.

Have a look in your app's `config/commands.rb` file and hopefully it is just a question of un-commenting the required lines.

There is little magic to the `origen specs` command that you see commonly used in Origen applications and plugins - it just wraps what you are already doing with the Origen command launcher.

The procedure is to follow the guide for how to add an application-specific command here: http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/commands/

And then the content of the `specs` command is simply:

```rb
# Run the unit tests  
when "specs"
  require "rspec"
  exit RSpec::Core::Runner.run(['spec'])
```

The above just programatically invokes RSpec on the application's spec directory, and assigns the exit code (i.e. pass/fail) from RSpec to the result of the `origen` command.